# How to use javax.ejb.TimerService in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timer, ejb

Working in a migration project, the actual project using TimerService from ejb jar. i want to migrate that to spring boot 2.4.2. While migrating springboot throws exception like timerService object is null, Actually Springboot not able to create object of TimerService even though I Autowired. Is there any altenative for EJB TimerService in Springboot or how to use the TimerService in Sprinboot.

Comment: Just slapping an `@Autowired` on a field doesn't mean it is automagically available. You will need to expose the `TimerService` as a bean. To expose it as a bean lookup the `TimerService` from JNDI so it is available. I believe you could use the `java:comp/TimerService` name to do the lookup. But as this is actually intended for EJBs your results might vary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554219/spring-alternative-to-timerservice-in-ejb-3